# Create iOS 13 Light/Dark wallpaper

Tags: customization, hacking, wallpaper

Does anybody know what kind of file are the wallpapers that came with iOS 13 that change with light / dark mode? I’d like to make one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic wallpapers are HEIC images which contain multiple images for light/dark. You can create your own with libheif and exiv2 in Terminal:

1. You need a XMP metadata blob, save this as `light_mode.xmp`:

```
<?xpacket?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns">
<rdf:Description xmlns:apple_desktop="http://ns.apple.com/namespace/1.0"
apple_desktop:apr=
"YnBsaXN0MDDSAQMCBFFsEAFRZBAACA0TEQ/REMOVE/8BAQAAAAAAAAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFQ=="/>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

2. Insert the XMP metadata: `exiv2 -i X in light_mode.png` (assumes `light_mode.xmp` exists)
3. Combine two images into one: `heif-enc -L light_mode.png dark_mode.png -o dynamic.heic`

I wrote up [a blog post about the details here](https://remove.codes/01-dynamic-wallpaper).

Answer (score -1):

I have a good feeling that the Dark/Light themed wallpapers work similarly to how Dark/Light themed images work with WebKit.

As of macOS Mojave, website developers can make their webpages change based on the system theme (light or dark). Websites that support dark mode will have at least 2 images, a dark-themed image and a light-themed image. When a user changes their theme from light to dark (or vise versa), the webpage will transition from one image to the other accordingly.

[image: A webpage image changing with Dark Mode]

For their light/dark wallpapers, Apple may have created two similar images and given them the exclusive ability to transition when the Dark Mode setting changes; but I cannot be 100% certain. If this is the case, they probably just use a standard image file format but made it so only they can make transitioning wallpapers.

Comment: I’m thinking maybe some kind of layered file?

Comment: the dynamic desktop wallpapers as well as the light/dark mode ones are multilayered HEIC images. You can e.g. use [dynamicwallpaper.club](https://dynamicwallpaper.club/) to create your own. Or any image processing software which supports layers and HEIC/HEIF-export.

Comment: Addendum II: [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) - as of version 2.10.2 and later - offers native HEIF support, including support for multiple images.

Comment: When we create these layered images, are we able to add them to iOS for use with light/dark mode? @slartibartfast

Comment: Please apologize that my previous comments are not sufficiently clear (that’s why I removed them). For use with iOS/iPadOS >13 you have to create a wallpaper bundle -  a "plain" light&dark image contains three seperate HEICs: the light version, the dark version, a "split view" thumbnail which is used in as preview in the Wallpaper preferences, and a binary property list file, all wrapped in to a wallpaper bundle. This is NOT the same as the *multi-image HEICs + .plist* which are used on MacOS.

Comment: if you use a  Mac and at least Xcode 11  you can explore this further by having a look in e.g. [WallpaperLoader](https://github.com/Skittyblock/WallpaperLoader). IMHO it is additionally recommended and helpfull to understand the differences between *still, image collection* and *image squence HEICs* to use them e.g. for "dynamic" wallpapers. [Nokia offers a nice collection of examples](https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/examples.html) you should be able to use and analyze with GIMP or Adobe's PS.

Comment: if you want to study the content of iOS/iPadOS wallpaper bundles you can e.g. download all iOS 14.2 wallpaper via [this](https://www.androidsage.com/2020/10/21/download-apple-ios-14-2-wallpapers/) page on Androidsage.

Comment: @slartibartfast, thanks a lot for your input! If you convert it into an answer I will award you the bounty